# HP elitebook 240 G3 touchpad bad performance

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, hp, synaptics

after upgrading from 16.04 LTS to 18.04.03 LTS on an HP EliteBook 840 G3 my touchpad now performs really badly, with very little options to set it up. The basic issues are:

- very (I mean, VERY) low sensitivity, i.e., I need to press or click the touchpad way more strongly than before
- very slow motion, even when set up at the max possible speed

Clicking works fine (here I refer to several post reporting right-click problems).

For information:

```
> xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And:

```
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/bionic,now 1.9.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

Any suggestion to improve my touchpad experience?

Cheers,
JP